# Could not find com.beloo.widget:ChipsLayoutManager:0.3.7

Tags: java, android, maven, jcenter, jitpack

I am using repositories mavenCentral() because jcenter() is deprecated. I want to implement com.beloo.widget:ChipsLayoutManager:0.3.7. But this is uploaded on jcenter().

Any Solutions to use com.beloo.widget:ChipsLayoutManager:0.3.7 in mavenCentral()

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
```

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.pchmn:MaterialChipsInput:1.0.8'
    implementation 'com.beloo.widget:ChipsLayoutManager:0.3.7'

}
```

Error:

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.beloo.widget:ChipsLayoutManager:0.3.7.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/beloo/widget/ChipsLayoutManager/0.3.7/ChipsLayoutManager-0.3.7.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/beloo/widget/ChipsLayoutManager/0.3.7/ChipsLayoutManager-0.3.7.pom
> - https://jitpack.io/com/beloo/widget/ChipsLayoutManager/0.3.7/ChipsLayoutManager-0.3.7.pom
> Required by:
> project :app
> project :app > com.github.pchmn:MaterialChipsInput:1.0.8

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Comment: There is an [open issue on the project's github about repositories](https://github.com/BelooS/ChipsLayoutManager/issues/69), just download and build the source yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If its not uploaded to Maven Central, then you can't get it from Maven Central.  These are file repositiories, they have to have the file to give it to you.  Use jcenter, download the code of the library and build it a as a local library, or find another library with similar functionality.

Comment: If I use jcenter() then I am facing duplicate class error.

Comment: Then remove MacenCentral.  Or move onto one of the other solutions.  You can't get the file from Maven Central if it doesn't have it.

Comment: Can I get this library from another source?

Comment: Sure, anywhere its uploaded to.  Most likely you can get the source code on github, I'd look there first.  If you mean is there a place where every piece of code is uploaded to so you can just use that-  not really.

Answer (score 0):

[It could be found at JitPack.io](https://jitpack.io/#BelooS/ChipsLayoutManager/v0.3.7) (You can try to search for any lib there.)
you should declare it as following:

```
implementation 'com.github.BelooS:ChipsLayoutManager:v0.3.7'
```